# How to parse a sine function?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have String input with a sin (b(x-c)) + d as its format. What is the delimiter expression I should use to split it so that I can use Integer.parse to obtain the numerical values for a, b, c and d?

So, if string input is

```
sin 5x                   a=1, b=5, c=d=0
sin 5(x-4)               a=1, b=5, c=4, d=0
2  sin 3(x-2)           a=2, b=3, c=2, d=0
sin 5x + 3               a=1, b=5, c=0, d=3
4  sin 7(x+6) + 2       a=4, b=7, c=-6, d=2
11  sin 2x              a=11, b=2, c=d=0
```

Comment: Is the format variable? Or this is the only format you want to parse?

Comment: string input may be sin 5x only, thus a = 1, c = d = 0

Comment: a = c = d = 0 makes the whole expression 0 not sin 5x

Comment: you need to define in your question all the possible variants of this expression

Comment: You need a Scanner class and the next int function. I'll write something up if I can get in my laptop today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a small parser for this. I don't think you can 
do it with regexp only but I haven't tried to prove that rigorously. 
Try this code. I haven't tested it on all your inputs though but it
should give you an idea.

```
public class Test002 {

    // private static String s = " 10 sin 5 ( x - 4 ) - 14 ";

    // private static String s = " 10 sin 2x ";

    private static String s = " -4  sin -7 (x+6) - 2 ";

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
        s = str;
        parseExpr();
    }

    private static void parseExpr(){
        parseA();
        parseSin();
        parseSinArgument();
        parseD();
    }

    private static void parseSinArgument(){
        parseB();
        if (s.charAt(i) == '('){
            parseOpenBracket();
            parseX();
            parseC();
            parseCloseBracket();
        }else{
            parseX();
        }
    }

    private static void parseA(){
        int j = i;
        while (s.charAt(i) != 's') i++;
        System.out.println("A=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
        // stay at the 's' now!
    }

    private static void parseSin(){
        int j = i;
        while (s.charAt(i) != 'n') i++;
        i++;
        // move past the 'n' now!
    }

    private static void parseB(){
        int j = i;
        while ( s.charAt(i) == '-' || Character.isDigit( s.charAt(i) )) i++;
        System.out.println("B=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static void parseOpenBracket(){
        int j = i;
        i++;
        System.out.println("OPEN_BRACKET=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static void parseX(){
        int j = i;
        while (s.charAt(i) != 'x') i++;
        i++;
        System.out.println("X=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static void parseC(){
        int j = i;
        while (s.charAt(i) != ')') i++;
        System.out.println("C=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static void parseCloseBracket(){
        int j = i;
        i++;
        System.out.println("CLOSE_BRACKET=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static void parseD(){
        int j = i;
        while (i<s.length()) i++;
        System.out.println("D=[" + getToken(j, i) + "]");
    }

    private static String getToken(int i1, int i2){
        String str = s.substring(i1, i2);
        str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
        return str.trim();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll just modify the code if input function has 0 c (i.e. sin 5x, sin 7x + 2, etc). But this is a good basis.

Comment: But it is totally restricted to exactly this format of the formular And I guess this is wath peter.petrov wanted to demonstrate.

Comment: @Ralf17 this a bad answer as it's going to be very prone to failing if the input changes. The other Peter's  answer is a much better starting point to *learn* how do answer this

Comment: @Pureferret What I was thinking of is how to parse that given format, and the use of delimiters is the only way I could think of at that time. So I asked how to use it to parse the input. Both answers may be correct but this one is within the scope of my understanding (I do not know how to build AST yet)

Comment: @Ralf17  I updated my code fixing a few bugs. I think this covers all the formats you need now (including c=0 and c!=0 and the presence/absence of brackets there). Before parsing, I get rid of all spaces, as I don't need them.

Comment: @Peter Yes, in this solution I wasn't trying to be too general. This is quick solution which works OK for this kind of expression. It is sort of based on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: @Pureferret Who said the input will change? I assumed this is the input format. If you think it's bad answer (for 20 mins of coding), provide your own answer.

Comment: No one ever says when the format will change,  but when it does this this will break. It's definitely not robust. Getting someone into the habit of this sort of coding is bad practice.  @Ralf17 learning (not just copying or memorising) is the act of expanding the scope of your understanding. Staying within your scope feels comfortable, but leads to too little growth.  Take this answer for now but look into Scanners and Tokenizers (don't worry about AST right now)

Comment: @Pureferret OK, I got your point. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @peter.petrov  
Like I commented on the question if I get access to my laptop I'll give it a crack.

Answer (score 2):

Puh. Whenever you are using strings to provide abstract contextes such as mathematical 
functions, you should consider writing:
A TokenScanner, which identifies tokens such as in your case:
function name 'sin',
operators '(', ')', '+'
constant tokens 1, 2, 5.
After token has been extracted from the string, you can start building an AST( abstract 
syntax tree).
By evaluating this tree you can then perform your caluclation.
See, if you got the numbers out of the formulas you postet above, which steps would you 
take further? Operators, numbers and even the function name itself can be at 
different places in your formular leaving you with an very complex analyzing on the string itself otherwise.
Building a token scanner is simple.
Building the AST seems to be more complicated, but isn't in this case, because the grammar 
of your expressions is not too complex. 
So instead of analyzing the whole string against the kind of expressions you are expecting, 
you are concentrated on how symbols are related to each other. E.g. sin(3 + (2 +4)). 
Gives you an AST of the form:
function 'sin' 
operator '(' 
const_value 3 
operator + 
operator '(' 
 const_value 2 
operator '+' 
const_value 4 
operator ')' 
operator ')'.
You can then traverse that tree for the innermost expressions, evaluate them and 
resubstitute the result of it. You know that each function - call creates a new scope 
and also every opening round bracket.
 So it's not hard to detect, which one are the innermost ones. The TokenScanner could basically be of the form:
Read the first char in the string, compare against the list of token, when it matches, 
build an object of that token type, read the next token , build an Object of that Token,
 link the both tokens e.g. via first and next - pointers and so on. 
To get an basic idea:

```
public class TokenScanner {
    public TokenScanner() { }
    public Token scan(String input) {
      Token root = new Token();
      Token prevToken = null;

      for(int i = 0; i < input.length(),i++) {
      Token newToken = null;
      char c = input.getCharAt(i);

      switch(c) {
        case 's': //** s is the start of the word sin, and not used in other contexts in this example, so: **/
        newToken = new FunctionToken();
        break;
        case '(':
          newToken = new Expression();
        case ')':
          newToken = new Expression();
        ....
      }
      if(prevToken == null) { 
        root->next = newToken;
        newToken->prev = root;
      }
      else {
        newToken->prev = prevToken;
        prevToken->next = newToken;
      }

      return root;
      }
    }
}

public class Token() {
    public Token prev;
    public Token next;
    public int TOKEN_TYPE = 0;

    public Token() {
    }
}

public class FunctionToken extends Token {
  static public int TOKEN_TYPE = 1;
}

public class Expression extends Token {
}

public class TokenTreeVisitor {
    public void traverse(Token currentToken) {
    switch(currentToken.TOKEN_TYPE) {
      case 1:
        enter((FunctionToken) currentToken);
    }
    }
}
```

**Though there is an interpreting of tokens already in this, so you should propably change Expression to OpenBracketToken and ClosingBracketToken for the tokenScanner. But it shows how you can get from the tokens to expressions and the expressions you can evaluate.**
This again is a process of checking if an expression contains subexpressions. If there 
 are any, process to that subexpression. If not, evaluate the subexpression and replace 
that expression in that tree with the result.
E.g.
Original subexpression (5 + (1 + 7))
Expression exp only containing const_value (1) , operator '+', const_value (7).
Evalute it by Int.parse(1) + INt.parse(7),

```
class ExpressionResult extends Expression {
     public int result;
}

result = new ExpressionResult(); result->result = 8;
exp->prev->next = result; result->prev = exp->prev; result->next =  exp->next;
```

Scan again and substitute recursive.
    exp2 now is const_value (5) + operator '+' + expression_result(8)

So you can Int.parse(5) + exp2->next->result;

and so on. Quiet trivial, isn't it? ;)

Comment: please format your answer!  It's almost unreadable as written.

Comment: I'd say this is only half right.  Constructing an AST is a good idea, but the OP's problem is not _evaluating_ the subsequent AST but _canonicalising_ it.

Comment: As included in the example.